# Using SUMPRODUCT instead of countif

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, sumproduct

I'm using SUMPRODUCT to count the number of times 'Jan-21' appears in a closed workbook. Current formual is:

=SUMPRODUCT(--('[Filepath]2021'!$D:$D="01/01/2021"))

Column D on the spreadsheet contains the word 'Jan-21' but in the formula bar it reads 01/01/2021 and tried this in the formula to no avail.

Basically I'd use a COUNTIF but we need the spreadsheet it's pulling from to remain closed hence I think SUMPRODUCT is the way forward.

Comment: `"01/01/2021"` is text. A date is a number. Try using `DATE(2021,1,1)`.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't error but still gives me 0 as the above formula does too.. 

Edit- this works, thank you. I was missing the '--' at the start of the formula.

Comment: try opening the target and recalc and see if it changes.

Comment: Sadly it does not.

Edit - As above I was missing the '--' at the start of the new formula. works now changing to date.